# VBScript aqConvert.IntToStr responds with 800A01A8

Tags: vbscript

I have following code:

```
Dim suffix
suffix = 0
Dim suffix_string
suffix_string = aqConvert.IntToStr(suffix)
```

and I'm getting the `Object Required: 'aqConvert'` . Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: What is `aqConvert`? VBScript doesn't have a built-in object like that, and you never instantiate it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

In VBScript, to convert to string you can just use [`CStr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk841e9):

```
suffix_string = CStr(suffix)
```